# Why \frenchsetup is no more defined when using \babelprovide

Tags: babel, pandoc, french

I try to compile this very small LaTeX code which used to work but is no more:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[main,import]{french}
\frenchsetup{ItemLabels=\textendash,og=«,fg=»}
\begin{document}
empty
\end{document}
```

Now `\frenchsetup` seems to be undefined.

Any idea why?

Just for information this is a simplification of code generated by pandoc which used to work but is not anymore.

I use TexLive 2020 (as distributed on Debian stable, aka `bullseye` as of today).

Comment: As far as I can see, this has never worked since `babel` introduced `\babelprovide`. The code in `french.ldf` is not loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\babelprovide[main,import]{french}` sets the *locale* to French, it provides proper hyphenation for French, sets the captions (f.i. `\tableofcontents` prints "Table des matières") and the date: `\today` will print the current date in French.

`\babelprovide[main,import]{french}` **does not** load the language definition file `french.ldf`, in particular `\frenchsetup` is **not** defined and has never been, as pointed out by @egreg. More significantly, no automatic spacing is provided for high punctuation (:;!?) in French.

Comment: Thank's Daniel. What is the new correct way to use french with babel?

Comment: @BrunoBEAUFILS See also https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/which-method-for-which-language.html

Answer (score 3):

Babel doc says that when a `.ldf` file is provided for your language, you should use it. So `\usepackage[french]{babel}` is still what you need.

I understand that you use Pandoc which deals only with the `\babelprovide` way  to define Babel's language.

Assuming that your document source is Markdown, the workaround is to set some YAML variables at the beginning :

````
---
classoption: french
header-includes:
- |
  ```{=latex}
  \let\languageshorthands\LanguageShortHands
  \frenchbsetup{og=«,fg=»}
  \usepackage{xspace}
  ```
...
````

This will pass the language option to the LaTeX document class (`article` by defautlt). Babel will inherit it.

It also reverts a command in Pandoc's default LaTeX template which inhibit French typographic rules regarding space and ponctuation, but also footnotes and other things.

Finaly it configures `«` and `»` to properly generate french guillemots in the LaTeX source (with the proper unbreakable fine space) and the `xspace` package is there to deal with the regular space needed (or not) after the closing guillemot.

You can even use the `\og` and `\fg` macros.